# Can I configure Celery Flower to run after I close my Unix shell?

Tags: unix, ssh, celery, flower

I have inherited a corporate server & application that consists of several python scripts, html files, and Unix services from an IT employee that recently left my company.  He left absolutely no documentation, so I'm struggling to support this application for my work group--I am not an IT professional (though I can read/write python, html, and a few other languages). I'm extremely unfamiliar with servers in general and Unix specifically.

From what I can tell from digging around, our application uses the following:

- nginx
- circus / gunicorn
- rabbitmq-server
- celery
- celery flower

I've finally got most of these services running, but I'm struggling with Celery Flower.  I've been able to launch Flower from my PuTTY SSH connection with the command:

```
/miniconda3/envs/python2/bin/flower start
```

but it appears to stop whenever I disconnect (server:5555 no longer shows the monitor web page).  Is it possible to configure it to run in the background so I don't have to keep my SSH connection open 24/7?  I saw in the Flower documentation that there is a persistence mode, but I'm not sure what does.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: hopefully you have access to the ex-empl's account? Login as that user and  run `crontab -l`. It may display a list of "crontab" entries and if you're lucky, you'll see that your `flower` component is being started there. You'll need to do a little reading about `cron` and `crontab`, which allow scheduling of jobs. while `man crontab` is the "official" way to learn, better to search for a tutorial on `crontab` (and maybe `cron`, `crond`). If that user also had `root` access, then repeat that process. ....

Comment: If you know you have other job-scheduling systems on that server, then dig in on how those are setup/configured and used. (Autosys anyone, there are many others). My comments are meant to help you uncover what is already setup and will be the simpilest to revive as a system. But this is only one track you may need to pursue, so save some energy OR lobby the boss to bring in a pro that can sort this out. It can be 1 of a million things. If you just want to rebuild the whole system, then read about `crontab -e` (this cmd arg can ruin an existing file, so ... careful!).

Comment: There are many, many crontab Qs here, so after reading a `crontab`  tutorial, scan some of the Qs to see if they help add to you knowledge. Then make a simple, "hello world " crontab entry, and see it work, then make some other simple tests and gradually work up to rebuilding your system in an environment that you created and understand. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the suggestions, @shellter!  I'll look into that stuff as well.  Unfortunately, the previous employee's system was wiped when he left.  Further, our group just laid off ~20% of our workforce, so hiring a pro here is almost certainly out of the question.

I just want to make sure I don't mess anything up, so I'm taking it slow.  I'll look into the cron stuff :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom,
I assume you are using a Linux platform. If this is the case I suggest you use screen (or even tmux) to run Flower. It will keep the application running in the background as well as offer the additional benefit of allowing you to connect back to the process if you need to inspect output, stop the process, etc.

To start the application use `screen -S Flower -d -m /miniconda3/envs/python2/bin/flower start`.

To see if the process is still running use `screen -ls` which will list the processes out like;

```
There is a screen on:
    17256.Flower    (02/09/16 08:01:16) (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-hooligan.
```

To connect back to it, use `screen -r Flower`.

If you have connected back to the screen then disconnect with `^a ^d`, assuming the escape character has not been changed from the default. To see a full list of key bindings look the the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Commands), it's pretty straight forward.

You might also consider adding this command to the system crontab with a `@REBOOT` directive so that it starts when the system boots.